# Active selector doesn't work after refresh

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx, progressive-web-apps

I have a react pwa app, within which a div with :active selector that slightly changes its color when pressed. It works perfectly but after page is refreshed :active selector seems to stop working, until app is relaunched. The bug only appears in Safari browser, Chrome works flawlessly.

```html
<div className="groups-button" onClick={e => this.update()}>
    <i className="material-icons">update</i>
    <p>Обновить расписание</p>
</div>
```

```js
update = () => {
    let group = localStorage.getItem("group") || "951007";
    localStorage.clear();
    localStorage.setItem("group", group);
    window.location.reload();
};
```

```css
.groups-button {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    transition: 0.05s background;
}

.groups-button:active {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the `window.location.reload` in your `update` method? That's probably causing the issue with `:active` styling. I've tested it in this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/css-active-style-with-react-lp2mg) - just the styling with-out reloading / localStorage.

Comment: @AWolf it turns out that indeed `window.location.reload` method is not required for this app but still would be great to find out the fix or workaround

Comment: Can you please check if the issue is also present in my linked Sandbox? I can not test it with Safari. FF and Chrome are working. I can not see the problem.

Comment: @AWolf well :active selector doesn’t work at all, I guess it’s the problem with touch-callout, in addition to that you don’t have a reload method there, as I mentioned above without reload it works perfectly